# How should I define a database connection in excel to have it work for different users/computers?

Tags: sql-server-2000, excel-2003

I've got an excel 2003 file that imports data from sql server 2000. Currently it only works for a specific user and computer.

How should I store/define the connection for it to work for different users/computers. The connection to the database uses SQL server authentication. The individual users have no permissions to access the database so a login is defined in SQL server.

However, when trying to open the file (which has the queries defined as refresh on open) from some different computers and under some different usernames we get the following error:

```
connection failed
SQLSTATE 28000
SQL server error 18456
[Microsoft][ODBC sql server driver][sql server] Login failed for user <username>
```

How do we fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know more about why the login itself failed.

Try: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx

To wit:

```
ERROR STATE | ERROR DESCRIPTION
2 and 5       Invalid userid
6             Attempt to use a Windows login name with SQL Authentication
7             Login disabled and password mismatch
8             Password mismatch
9             Invalid password
11 and 12     Valid login but server access failure
13            SQL Server service paused
18            Change password required
```

Comment: If I look at the errorlog, I don't see anything but the login failure. How do I see those error states?

Comment: You're looking at the error log on the SQL Server machine? What does that error log show? Also, you might check if SQL logging is set to log the information you're looking for. Try http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739187%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: 2011-01-30 11:08:16.49 logon     Login failed for user '<domain name>\<user name>'.
2011-01-30 11:08:56.49 logon     Login failed for user '<domain name>\<user name>'.
2

Comment: If the 2 at the end of your comment is part of the error, then it's invalid userid. Doublecheck your username and domain.

Comment: No sorry, it's not part of the error, that's the beginning of the next line. In any case, just to test, I made a new excel file, and put in a single database query using the same connection. Then I opened the file on another computer under another user (not an administrator). This time I did not get the error. I did earlier check all the queries in the other file and all use this same connection.

Comment: It still seems like there is an error log that should exist with a more descriptive error message. With the test file, if you open that on the computer giving you the problem, do you still get the error? In other words, is it computer-domain related instead of user-domain related? Or maybe a firewall issue?

Comment: I've managed to solve the problem in a different manner. The excel file had a number of sheets. I cut it in two (each with half of the sheets), only one of the parts exhibited the problem and so on until I found the offending sheet. There I copied all the database queries to a text file and then deleted the queries in the sheet. Then I added them in again with the correct connection and things worked. The problem is now, if it reappears, how do I redefine the database connection for a specific query?

Comment: Hmm. That sounds as if the VBA got borked on compile and mangled your connection settings. Hmm. Either that, or the file had been corrupted in some way. I don't know. When you say "redefine the db connection for a specific query", do you mean the VBA code itself? Or create another db connection instance that doesn't share the same underlying connection?

Comment: Remove the queries as they are, and then create a new query, using the same db connection as in the test file I made. Btw, I did not do anything explicitly in VBA.